# What's the K-group of a surface?

Tags: algebraic-topology, surfaces, topological-k-theory

What's the K-group of a surface? I also want to know how to calculate such group and if there is a explicit characterization of the generators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a "fundamental domain" for your surface, then you can use basic obstruction theory to compute this explicitly (or at least reduce it to pure group theory).  Recall that we have the natural isomorphism $K(X) \cong [X,BU\times \mathbb{Z}]$, and $\pi_1(BU)\cong \pi_0(U)=0$.  So, the 1-skeleton of any CW-complex maps essentially trivially into $BU$, and hence $[\Sigma,BU] \cong \pi_2(BU)$ for any such surface $\Sigma$ with a fundamental domain.  Then, we can compute that $\pi_2(BU) = \mathbb{Z}$ by Bott periodicity (or you can easily compute by hand that $\pi_1(U)=\mathbb{Z}$).  So, $K(\Sigma)\cong \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$.

So, this brings us to computing $K(S^2)$:
$$K(S^2) \cong [S^2,BU \times \mathbb{Z} ] \cong \pi_2(BU) \times \mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}.$$
The nontrivial copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ is generated by the (vdim-0) *Hopf bundle*, namely the canonical bundle over $\mathbb{CP}^1$ minus $\underline{\mathbb{C}}$.  Moreover, If $\Sigma$ is a surface with a fundamental domain (i.e. any surface of positive genus), then by the description I've given above, you can obtain a generator for the first copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ (i.e., the copy not picking off virtual dimension) via pullback along the map $\Sigma \rightarrow S^2$ which collapses the 1-skeleton to a point.

Of course, you could have just done this with arbitrary CW decompositions all along.  But most surfaces admit one with a single 2-cell, which simplifies the computation considerably.

Comment: I found this while searching for something else, and I want to point out that it isn’t quite right.  It seems to claim that the K-theory of any 2-dimensional CW-complex with a single 2-cell is the same as the 2-sphere, which is wrong (eg a disk has such a CW-complex structure).  The argument in the answer shows that the map from the K-theory of the sphere to the K-theory of the space is surjective, but it is not always injective.

Comment: @AndyPutman Ah, thank you for pointing that out! Indeed, I used cellular approximation for maps, but I forgot that when you use cellular approximation for homotopies things bump up a dimension.

Answer (score 2):

With the caveat that I haven't done this computation myself, I suggest having a look at the Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence, which computes generalised cohomology of a space in terms of the ordinary cohomology and the coefficients of the generalised theory.

Comment: I agree - this and the Chern character (which can get you the non-rational part)

Comment: Doesn't the Chern character *only* give you the rational part?