# Complex (topological) K-theory of $S \Sigma$ for a surface $\Sigma$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-k-theory

In the following question here:

[What's the K-group of a surface?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197626/whats-the-k-group-of-a-surface)

The $K$-theory of a compact orientable surface is computed. I was curious if it was also possible to compute the "higher" $K$-groups as well. My understanding is that, by Bott periodicity, it would suffice to compute $K(S \Sigma)$, where $S \Sigma$ is the suspension of $\Sigma$. Moreover, I think that one can do this rationally by comparing it to rational cohomology. Is it easy to compute $K(S \Sigma)$ integrally?

Comment: The most elementary way to compute $K(S\Sigma)$ is probably to use the fact that $S\Sigma$ is homotopy equivalent to a wedge of spheres. Thinking of $\Sigma$ as a CW complex with a single 2-cell attached by the usual commutator relation describing $\pi_1 (\Sigma)$, one checks that after suspending, the attaching map becomes nullhomotopic (essentially because it is still a commutator, but now lives in an abelian group (namely $\pi_2$ of the suspension of the one-skeleton of $\Sigma$). Now $K(S\Sigma)$ can be read off from the homotopy groups of $\mathbb{Z}\cross BU$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below by $B^n A$ I mean the Eilenberg-MacLane space $K(A, n)$.

The Chern character isomorphism tells you how to compute rational K-theory; in this case it gives

$$K^0(\Sigma) \otimes \mathbb{Q} \cong H^0(\Sigma, \mathbb{Q}) \times H^2(\Sigma, \mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Q}^2$$

$$K^1(\Sigma) \otimes \mathbb{Q} \cong H^1(\Sigma, \mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Q}^{2g}.$$

In other words, rational K-theory is periodic rational cohomology. It turns out that in this case integral K-theory is also periodic integral cohomology; that is, the following holds.

> **Theorem:** Let $\Sigma$ be a compact orientable surface of genus $g$. Then
>
> $$K^0(\Sigma) \cong [\Sigma, \mathbb{Z} \times BU] \cong H^0(\Sigma, \mathbb{Z}) \times H^2(\Sigma, \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}^2$$
>
> $$K^1(\Sigma) \cong [\Sigma, U] \cong H^1(\Sigma, \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}^{2g}.$$

We will give three proofs of this.

**Proof 1: the Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence.**

This is a spectral sequence

$$H^p(\Sigma, K^q(\text{pt})) \to K^{p+q}(\Sigma)$$

which in this case degenerates at the $E_2$ page. All of the groups appearing on the $E_2$ page are free abelian, so there are no extension problems and we get isomorphisms

$$K^0(\Sigma) \cong H^0(\Sigma, \mathbb{Z}) \times H^2(\Sigma, \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}^2$$

$$K^1(\Sigma) \cong H^1(\Sigma, \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}^{2g}.$$

as desired. $\Box$

**Proof 2: obstruction theory in the source.**

We'll describe more generally a computation of $[\Sigma, Y]$ for a nice space $Y$.

> **Theorem:** Let $Y$ be a path-connected space with $\pi_1(Y)$ abelian and the action of $\pi_1(Y)$ on $\pi_2(Y)$ trivial. Then
>
> $$[\Sigma, Y] \cong \text{Hom}(\pi_1(\Sigma), \pi_1(Y)) \times \pi_2(Y).$$

*Proof.* Pick a basepoint for $\Sigma$ and for $Y$. We will first work out the answer with a basepoint and then remove the dependence on it later.

As Mariano says in the comments, the starting point is to think of a compact orientable surface $\Sigma$ of genus $g$ as the mapping cone, or homotopy cofiber, of the map $S^1 \to (S^1)^{\vee 2g}$ given on fundamental groups by the inclusion of $[a_1, b_1] ... [a_g, b_g]$. We know how to map the $1$-skeleton $(S^1)^{\vee 2g}$ into an arbitrary pointed space; this is precisely a $2g$-tuple of loops in $Y$ based at the same point. The identification of $\Sigma$ as the homotopy cofiber of a map from $S^1$ tells us that the space of extensions of a pointed map $(S^1)^{\vee 2g} \to Y$ to a pointed map $\Sigma \to Y$ is precisely the space of null-homotopies of the image of the loop $[a_1, b_1] ... [a_g, b_g]$ in $Y$.

Passing to homotopy classes, we want to identify the space of homotopy classes of pairs consisting of $2g$ based loops $a_1, b_1, ..., a_g, b_g$ in $Y$ and a null-homotopy of the loop $[a_1, b_1] ... [a_g, b_g]$. This data gives us in particular an element of $\text{Hom}(\pi_1(\Sigma), \pi_1(Y))$, but there is extra data given by the choice of null-homotopy. In general, the homotopy classes of null-homotopies of a loop in $Y$ are an affine space over $\pi_2(Y)$, and so in particular noncanonically in bijection with $\pi_2(Y)$. We may furthermore replace the loop by a homotopic loop, but this doesn't matter since the action of $\pi_1(Y)$ on $\pi_2(Y)$ is trivial. This gives

$$[\Sigma, Y]_{\ast} \cong \text{Hom}(\pi_1(\Sigma), \pi_1(Y)) \times \pi_2(Y)$$

(noncanonically), where $[-, -]_{\ast}$ denotes based homotopy classes. The above argument works with any choice of basepoint in $Y$, so now consider the effect of freely changing basepoints in $Y$, which is one way to think of what happens when we pass to unbased homotopy classes. Picking distinguished paths from the basepoint we started with in $Y$ to all other basepoints, the result, after translating to the basepoint we started with, is that all of the data above gets acted on by $\pi_1(Y)$ (by conjugation on $\pi_1(Y)$ and by the usual action on $\pi_2(Y)$), but by hypothesis this action is trivial and the result follows. $\Box$

To complete the computation, applying the theorem above gives

$$[\Sigma, \mathbb{Z} \times BU] \cong \mathbb{Z} \times \pi_2(BU) \cong \mathbb{Z}^2$$

$$[\Sigma, U] \cong \text{Hom}(\pi_1(\Sigma), \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}^{2g}$$

since in the first case $\pi_1$ vanishes and in the second case $\pi_1$ is abelian and $\pi_2$ vanishes. $\Box$

**Proof 3: obstruction theory in the target.**

Mostly as an exercise for me, I want to make use of the following general result.

> **Theorem:** Let $X$ be a finite CW-complex of dimension at most $n$, let $Y$ be a space with a Postnikov tower of principal fibrations, and let $Y_n$ be the $n$-truncation of $Y$. Then the map $Y \to Y_n$ induces a bijection
>
> $$[X, Y] \cong [X, Y_n].$$

The $n$-truncation $Y_n$ of a space is a space together with a map $Y \to Y_n$ inducing isomorphisms on $\pi_k, 0 \le k \le n$ and such that all higher homotopy of $Y_n$ vanishes. It can be constructed from $Y$ by attaching cells of suitably high dimensions to kill all of the higher homotopy of $Y$. In particular, by definition it satisfies $[S^k, Y] \cong [S^k, Y_n]$ for all $0 \le k \le n$, and the theorem just says that this implies the corresponding fact not only for these spheres but for spaces built out of them.

*Proof.* The truncation map $Y \to Y_n$ induces a map $[X, Y] \to [X, Y_n]$ and we want to show that it is a bijection. We'll do this by proving a corresponding bijection for the entire Postnikov tower

$$\cdots \to Y_{n+2} \to Y_{n+1} \to Y_n \to \cdots$$

of $Y$. By hypothesis, the spaces in the Postnikov tower fit into principal fibrations giving fibration sequences

$$B^{n+1} \pi_{n+1}(Y) \to Y_{n+1} \to Y_n \xrightarrow{k_n} B^{n+2} \pi_{n+1}(Y).$$

Any map $X \to Y_n$ induces a map $X \to B^{n+2} \pi_{n+1}(Y)$ giving a cohomology class in $H^{n+2}(X, \pi_{n+1}(Y))$, and $X$ lifts to a map $X \to Y_{n+1}$ if and only if this cohomology class vanishes. But in this case we know that $H^{n+2}(X, -)$ vanishes with any coefficients, so a lift always exists; hence $[X, Y_{n+1}] \to [X, Y_n]$ is surjective.

Knowing that a lift exists, the set of (weak) homotopy classes of lifts is an affine space over $[X, B^{n+1} \pi_{n+1}(Y)] \cong H^{n+1}(X, \pi_{n+1}(Y))$, which also vanishes; hence lifts are unique up to homotopy, and $[X, Y_{n+1}] \to [X, Y_n]$ is a bijection. By induction $[X, Y_{n+k}] \to [X, Y_n]$ is a bijection for all $k \ge 0$, and by reconstructing $Y$ as the homotopy limit over the $Y_{n+k}, k \ge 0$ we get a bijection $[X, Y] \cong [X, Y_{n+k}], k \ge 0$. $\Box$

To complete the computation, $U$ and $BU$ both have abelian fundamental groups which act trivially on their higher homotopy (since they are both infinite loop spaces); these are the spaces which have Postnikov towers of principal fibrations, so the above theorem applies to them. Applying the theorem gives

$$[\Sigma, \mathbb{Z} \times BU] \cong \mathbb{Z} \times H^2(\Sigma, \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}^2$$

$$[\Sigma, U] \cong H^1(\Sigma, \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}^{2g}$$

since the $2$-truncations of $BU$ and $U$ both have a single nonzero homotopy group and hence must be Eilenberg-MacLane spaces, namely $B^2 \mathbb{Z}$ and $B \mathbb{Z}$ respectively. $\Box$

All three proofs show more generally that integral K-theory agrees with periodic integral cohomology for any finite CW-complex of dimension at most $2$. For finite CW-complexes of dimension $3$, the third proof tells you that this continues to hold for $K^0$, but for $K^1$ the $3$-truncation of $U$ may be an interesting homotopy $3$-type.

Comment: Another approach is to use the clutching construction,  which leaves you with describing maps out of the abelianization of the fundamental group of the surface, which is very easy (and shows that most of the technology you mention is not really needed :-))

Comment: @Mariano: I understand the clutching construction to be essentially  the identification of $K^1(\Sigma)$ with $[\Sigma, U]$. I don't see how to identify this with $\text{Hom}(\pi_1(\Sigma), \mathbb{Z})$ without at least a little additional effort (although perhaps the third alternative involving thinking about a CW-decomposition of $\Sigma$ is the simplest method). What argument do you have in mind?

Comment: Thank you. I particularly appreciate that you gave several arguments, which is helpful when learning a subject for the first time.

Comment: @user: I worry that the second argument above is unnecessarily complicated though, like Mariano says. I think it can be simplified as follows: $Y_n$ can be made from $Y$ by attaching $k$-cells for $k \ge n+2$, so we can choose CW-models of $Y$ and $Y_n$ which have the same $n+1$-skeleton, hence maps into either land in the $n+1$-skeleton up to homotopy and moreover homotopies between maps into either also land in the $n+1$-skeleton up to homotopy.

Comment: Write the surface as the mapping cone of a map $S^1\to(S^1)^{\vee g}$. The map $[f]\in[\Sigma,U]\to\pi_1(f)\in\hom(\pi_1\Sigma,\pi_1U)$ is surjective because of the usual property of mapping cones, and it is injevtive because $\pi_2U=0$, I guess.

Comment: @Mariano: cool, that's essentially the third argument I had in mind. Probably it is the simplest.

Comment: I don't recall how involved it is to see that $\pi_2U=0$, honestly, but up to that (and the clutching construction, of course) it's very elementary.

Comment: @Mariano: it is quite straightforward; it is equivalent to show that $\pi_2(SU) = 0$, and we know that $\pi_2(SU(2)) \cong \pi_2(S^3) = 0$ and that $\pi_2$ stabilizes after this.

Comment: @Mariano: I've edited in a more general version of the argument you suggest. I think it is a bit tricky to work out the details in this generality, although maybe there are some simplifications I'm not aware of.